# MAUI iOS App ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols

Tags: ios, app-store, maui, maui-community-toolkit

When I submit the App to Appstore it is rejected with the following error:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
> symbols in : _ubrk_openRules, _ucal_add, _ucal_close,
> _ucal_get, _ucal_getAttribute, _ucal_getKeywordValuesForLocale, _ucal_getNow, _ucal_getTimeZoneDisplayName, _ucal_getTimeZoneIDForWindowsID, _ucal_getWindowsTimeZoneID, _ucal_open, _ucal_openTimeZoneIDEnumeration, _ucal_set, _ucal_setMillis, _ucol_close, _ucol_closeElements, _ucol_getOffset, _ucol_getRules, _ucol_getSortKey, _ucol_getStrength, _ucol_getVersion, _ucol_next, _ucol_open, _ucol_openElements, _ucol_openRules, _ucol_previous, _ucol_safeClone, _ucol_setAttribute, _ucol_setVariableTop, _ucol_strcoll, _ucurr_forLocale, _ucurr_getName, _udat_close, _udat_countSymbols, _udat_format, _udat_getSymbols, _udat_open, _udat_setCalendar, _udat_toPattern, _udata_setCommonData, _udatpg_close, _udatpg_getBestPattern, _udatpg_open, _uenum_close, _uenum_count, _uenum_next, _uldn_close, _uldn_keyValueDisplayName, _uldn_open, _uloc_canonicalize, _uloc_countAvailable, _uloc_getAvailable, _uloc_getBaseName, _uloc_getCharacterOrientation, _uloc_getCountry, _uloc_getDefault, _uloc_getDisplayCountry, _uloc_getDisplayLanguage, _uloc_getDisplayName, _uloc_getISO3Country, _uloc_getISO3Language, _uloc_getKeywordValue, _uloc_getLCID, _uloc_getLanguage, _uloc_getName, _uloc_getParent, _uloc_setKeywordValue, _ulocdata_getCLDRVersion, _ulocdata_getMeasurementSystem, _unorm2_getNFDInstance, _unorm2_getNFKCInstance, _unorm2_getNFKDInstance, _unorm2_isNormalized, _unum_close, _unum_getAttribute, _unum_getSymbol, _unum_open, _unum_toPattern, _ures_close, _ures_getByKey, _ures_getSize, _ures_getStringByIndex, _ures_open, _usearch_close, _usearch_first, _usearch_getBreakIterator, _usearch_getMatchedLength, _usearch_last, _usearch_openFromCollator, _usearch_setPattern, _usearch_setText.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Comunity Edition (v17.7) to compile and build the app. The app targets only iOS platform, I have removed Windows, Android and Mac from the targetted platforms list.

MAUI Version:

[image]

Third-Party Nuget Packages Installed:

- Newtonsoft.Json
- Onion.Maui.Googlemaps
- SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui
- Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Database
- CommunityToolkit.Maui

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled "Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Database" plugin and the release build got accepted in the store. To implement Firebase Realtime Database functionality, I used FirebaseDatabase.net plugin.

This seems to be a lesser known issue with Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Database as reported here: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/617